# Windows Phone 8 Re-theme Application on activation

Tags: windows-phone-8

I was looking for a way to apply the current theme to the application on application activation.
E.g. the app is started in light theme and the user switches to the settings to switch to dark theme. Now when he comes back to my app, he still sees a white theme until he restarts the app.
I found several older blogs and stackoverflow links which stated that this is a bug in WP7.
But when I tried this with the calculator app or the people app (both from Microsoft), they are visually rethemed once I reactivate them.

Any idea how this can be achieved on Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a low priority bug to me. :) Anyway you can use [PhoneThemeManager](http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager) to change the theme for the app manually.

Comment: Sure, it is a low priority bug only.
Unfortunately it is not so easy to use any third party libs in my company :-(